# iTunes showing no result found if searching for tracks from application

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, itunes, itunes-store

I'm opening the the itunes using this link on iPhone

http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?term=

But while the link redirect to iTunes, It do not provide search result and showing 'No result' error.

While the same link is working on mac. If I search for some track on browser, it opens the iTunes store and showing search result. Same thing is not happening with iPhone.

**Note: The link is working with iOS version 7.x but not on 8.x. Is this related to iOS issues or Itunes Issues. Not sure.**

Please suggest.

Comment: On iOS it seems that ("") is added to the search term, making it unfindable.  
search_term => ("search_term")

Comment: It is unfindable. I just put those in the question to represent some string. Let me edit those.